# How do I get rid of my PIN on Window 10?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, pin

I am just getting started using a Windows 10 based tablet computer; every time I want to use my new computer now, ever time the screen times out, I have to use my email password.
I also do not want the PIN feature, because it will access sites with passwords that have to change. There is no apparent way to allow you to update changed passwords with the PIN feature.
Please tell me how I can eliminate the need for a password to open my computer, and eliminate the use of the PIN "shortcut"

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below which explains how to remove the Windows 10 Pin.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6518-pin-remove-your-account-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably was tricked to create or use existing Microsoft's account when you start using device. The easiest way IMHO would be to create a new LOCAL(!!!) account and move data, bookmarks and etc to a new account. Another option is to switch M$ account to a local one by following this [guide](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-switch-back-to-a-local-account-from-a-microsoft-account/)